# Rails 5 - how to call a class method in \lib from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an app to learn Rails and am trying to understand the principle concept of rails for this case (apologize my ignorance, am new):

When clicking a button on the screen (in a form), I want to perform a certain function - a method called `set_documenttype` in `distiller.rb` - while staying in the view.

As per "pick-axe" book for Rails 5, I have put it in `/lib/distiller` and in:

- `DocumentsController.rb` I have set:

  `class DocumentsController < ApplicationController
      require "distiller/distiller"`
- `application.rb` I have set `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

`distiller.rb`

```
class Distiller

    def set_documenttype(f)
        #=> do something here
    end

end
```

Now, I am getting

> NoMethodError in Documents#edit
>
> undefined method `link_to_set_documenttype' for ....

Thanks for helping me understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try `helper_method : set_documenttype` to declare a controller method as a helper,  available to the view.

If still doesn't work, please share the source of `distiller.rb`

Comment: didn't work - some error; added distiller.rb (which is still empty)

Comment: rebooted and works as helper - yeah ; how can I get it working from distiller in /lib?

Comment: any chance giving me a help with this one? I becoming crazier than ever ;-(